# onClick event not working for button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to show forms based on the button clicked. That is, on clicking the first button, two other buttons are displayed. However, the new buttons generated behave like dummy buttons (`onClick` event not working).

How can I resolve this error? Is there any alternative for this to implement the same functionality?

---

I have the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Frequently Asked Questions</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSSfiles/faqCSS.css">  
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script >
        function addContent(divName, content) {
            document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML = content;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Put banner and logo on top; Put footer later </p>
    <div class="intro">
        Looking for help? We provide you information about what can be done when in trouble. Hope you find it helpful!
    </div>


    <form name="myForm" class="select">
        <input type="button" value="ND" class="select-button" onClick="addContent('myDiv', document.myForm1.ND.value);"><br>
        <input type="button" value="E" class="select-button" onClick="addContent('myDiv', document.myForm1.E.value);">
    </form>

    <form name="myForm1" class="select">
        <textarea   name="ND">
            <input type="button" value="Earthquakes" class="trial" onclick="addContent('yourDiv', document.myForm2.HW.value);"/><br>
        </textarea>
        <textarea  name="E"><u>E</u></textarea>
    </form>

    <form name="myForm2" class="select">
        <textarea   name="HW">
            <u>Hello world!</u>
        </textarea>
    </form>

    <br><br>

    <div id="myDiv"></div>
    <div id="yourDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: New elements added dynamically to the DOM won't have any event listeners attached to them until you do.

Comment: you need to read about event delegaion

Comment: You need to use lower jquery version and then use live function of jquery. May be it's not the perfect answer but it may help you.

Comment: @ajaykumartak — live had a replacement before it was removed from jQuery, there is no need to use an obsolete version of the library.

Comment: @Quentin Sorry my bad i will google it now.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear to me how you add the buttons to your DOM (could you post that code?).

However, say that your button has an id of 'MyButton1',

```
 <button id="MyButton1">Hello</button>
```

then **if you do this with jQuery**, your code needs to have it [*delegate*](http://api.jquery.com/on/) the click, by hooking an object that is already existing and will contain your button; for example the `body` element:

```
// This is registered before MyButton1 is created.

$('body').on('click', '#MyButton1', function(event) {
    alert("Hello, I'm button 1");
}
```

Using **plain javascript**, *after* you have created the new content (so that `getElementById` can find the button), you need to bind the onclick event:

```
document.getElementById('MyButton1').onclick = function() {
    alert("Hello again");
}
```

or (not supported on older IEs)

```
document.getElementById('MyButton1').addEventListener("click",
   function() {
       alert("Still me");
   });
```

Here you can find [**a Javascript fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LknmLhmm/) with code re: the javascript method.

Answer (score -1):

Initially keep all forms hidden. Put them in the desired division. Onclick of each button only show/hide intended form..

This can help you out.